# Need to copy a column from on Sheet to another based on a value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I have 2 Excel Sheets.
I want to copy the values from the "CategoryIds" column to another sheet 
that has a matching column on the SKU field of that sheet.

I need the "CategoryIds" column in this sheet : NewDepotProdsDB.xls,

to be copied into this sheet : DEPOT_products.xlsx,

based on a match with the "SKU" column.

```
NewDepotProdsDB.xls  :
SKU  CategoryIds
5845 8 
8545 58
...


DEPOT_products.xlsx :
SKU  CategoryIds
5845 > need to copy the value from NewDepotProdsDB.xls here >
8545 > need to copy the value from NewDepotProdsDB.xls here >
....
```

Is this possible to do?

I could temporarily copy those 2 columns (SKU CategoryIds)
to the DEPOT_products.xlsx sheet and then use a formula or something for this.
I'm not good at Excel and dont' really know what I'm doing.

Note : I have the 97-2003 version of Excel.

Thanks

Comment: Getting confused here - what do you mean by "based on a match with the SKU column". Do both sheets have a SKU column? Can you create a simple example of what needs to be copied where? Did you try things like using `MATCH` to find the right column? By the way - you are using a very old version of Excel. Could it be time for an upgrade? Once every ten years isn't too aggressive...

Comment: Yes, each sheet has a "SKU" column. I need to match that column from one sheet and then copy the value of the "CategoryIds" column into the other sheet. I put and example above.

Comment: Do you expect all SKU from one sheet to have a corresponding one in the other? What do you want to do with "non matched" rows?

Comment: Yes. They have exactly the same number of rows and matching SKU's in each worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You should add this macros to file DEPOT_products.xlsx. I suppose that your data are in Sheet1 in each file in columns A and B (starting from the second row), but you can easily change it if it isn't true for you:

```
Sub test()

   Dim Wb1 As Workbook
   Dim Wb2 As Workbook
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet
   Dim sh2 As Worksheet
   Dim lastrow1 As Long
   Dim lastrow2 As Long
   Dim vlookup As String

   On Error GoTo ErrHandler

   'current workbook (DEPOT_products.xlsx)'
   Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook

   'path to the NewDepotProdsDB.xls file'
   Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\NewDepotProdsDB.xls", ReadOnly:=True
   Set Wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

   'set correct name of the sheet with your data in file DEPOT_products.xlsx'
   Set sh1 = Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")

   'set correct name of the sheet with your data in file NewDepotProdsDB.xls'
   Set sh2 = Wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

   'determining last row of your data in file DEPOT_products.xlsx'
   lastrow1 = sh1.Range("A" & sh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'determining last row of your data in file NewDepotProdsDB.xls'
   lastrow2 = sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'write the formula to match your SKU column in DEPOT_products.xlsx to SKU column in NewDepotProdsDB.xls and get column CategoryIds'
   vlookup = "VLOOKUP(A2," & "[" & Wb2.Name & "]" _
       & sh2.Name & "!" & "$A$2:$B$" & lastrow2 _
       & ",2, 0)"
   sh1.Range("B2:B" & lastrow1).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(" & vlookup & ")," _
        & """not found""" & "," & vlookup & ")"

   'copy formulas result and paste them like a values (to kill formulas) - you can comment the code below, so you will have formulas instead values'
   sh1.Range("B2:B" & lastrow1).Copy
   sh1.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False


   ' close NewDepotProdsDB.xls
   Wb2.Close False

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "File not found: " + Err.Description
    Else
        MsgBox "Unknown error: " + Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps. I've tried to comment the code in details, but if you have some questions, ask please.

**UPD:**
Alternatively you can use formula instead VBA code. Just write it in DEPOT_products.xlsx in the sheet with your data (column CategoryIds):

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'C:\Work\[NewDepotProdsDB.xls]Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$500,2,0)),"not found",VLOOKUP(A2,'C:\Work\[NewDepotProdsDB.xls]Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$500,2,0))
```

1) change `A2` to address of your first SKU in DEPOT_products.xlsx and put this formula to the cell, corresponding the first CategoryIds

2) change `'C:\Work\[NewDepotProdsDB.xls]Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$500` to the path of your NewDepotProdsDB.xls file + correct sheet + correct range of SKU and CategoryIds.

3) drop this formula down to the last row with SKU

Comment: Haven't tried running this, but looks right. Could use a `For Each` loop as an alternative, but this is probably quicker. Leaving the formulas in place will slow the sheet down a bit but does leave it "live" which is quite nice. Might want to think what to do if no match is found… leave error or leave empty?

Comment: using formulas is much faster than `For Each`. It depends on the situations, but I think the best way to add next construction, if you use excel 97-2003: `=If(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(...)),"not found",VLOOKUP(...))`. If you use excel 2007, than you can use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...),"not found")`

Comment: @Floris, thank you for you advice about not matched values..I've changed the code

Comment: 99% of the difference between ok code and good code is error handling / "edge cases".

Comment: Thanks for the code. How do I add add the macro to file DEPOT_products.xlsx? I using Excel Starter too. Does that have it?

Comment: unfortunately you can't use VBA in starter edition. It's one of the features that are disabled. It's available in the Standard or Premium editions. I can provide you a formula, that can do the similar thing to my code

Comment: To make it easier, could I copy the 2 columns (SKU CategoryIds) from the NewDepotProdsDB to the DEPOT_products.xlsx sheet, then use a formula to fill in the missing CategoryIDs values? This way it will all be on one sheet. Then I could just delete the 2 columns later.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you can copy data into one workbook, the formula would be easier (you can just remove path to file + sheet name, and leave only range address $A$2:$B$500, changing it into the correct one)

Comment: If you expect all SKU from one sheet to have a corresponding one in the other, you can just write `=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$2:$B$500,2,0)` in the B2 cell

Comment: Thanks again. I copied the 2 columns over. The SKU fields are in columns P and CC. The CategoryIds column with the data I need is in CD. The column that needs to be filled in is in BW. How do I plug those columns in the =VLOOKUP()? I'm not very good with Excel.

Comment: write this formula in BW1: `=VLOOKUP(P1,CC:CD,2,0)` and drop it down

Comment: Worked great. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the vlookup formula.

Example:

if the SKU values are in B col, starting from 5th row in depot_product xlsx and the category ids and sku values are in sheet2 of NewDepotProdsDB (in C14 to D15) cells, then you can use the following formula.

=VLOOKUP(B5,[NewDepotProdsDB.xls]Sheet2!$C$14:$D$15,2,0)

the number 2 tells the excel to fetch the values from 2nd column from sku id column.